# How to switch on SQL queries logging with EF and Postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I saw the following `appsettings.json` variant in the Adam Freeman's book:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyAppDb": "connection string"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"   
    }
  }
}
```

Then author tells:

> This logging configuration will let you see the messages produced by Entity Framework Core that reveal
>   the SQL commands that are sent to the database and prevent them from being lost in a stream of other
>   messages.

I  would like to see which SQL `EF` makes for my database. Unfortunately, the above approach does not work. Maybe it's happening because I'm using `postgres` and `Npgsql` and I have to put another setting in the `appsettings.file`? I have tried this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyAppDb": "connection string"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "Information"   
    }
  }
}
```

But without success( Just silence in the console. Pleas, help. Thank you.

Comment: You can set `log_statement = all` on the pg server side. See [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-logging.html)

Comment: @clamp thank you, but I would like to see exactly this feature. I mean debug console of a running .NET Core application. It seems that it  works for SQL Server. I hope it works for PostgreSQL too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using .NET Core 3.1, Npgsql 4.1.5, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.4, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design 1.1.0.

SQL statements *are* logged out to Output window and the console (when running the Project).

appSettings.json (very similar to yours)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "xxxxx"
  }

}
```

Example of output:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT p.id, p.country_id, p.dob, p.gender, p.handed, p.height_feet, p.height_inches, p.home_town, p.name, p.photo, p.turned_pro, p.weight
FROM tennis2.player AS p
WHERE p.id = @__p_0
LIMIT 1
```

So I would persevere.